# Click Same Item Every Time Listview Android

Tags: android

When I click Every Time Show Same Item Click What is the solution ?
How can i solve this.
I use Android List view and as Database use Firebase.
I want To categorize List As Prioritry.

Your Help will be appreciate me.

```
public class BloodReqActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView listview;
SearchView searchView;
FirebaseDatabase database;
ArrayList<String> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Blood_Request_Model blood_request_model;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public String key, blood, name, phone, location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_req);

    listview = findViewById(R.id.bloodlist);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.adsearchView);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BloodReqActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();


    blood_request_model = new Blood_Request_Model();

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.user_info, R.id.useInfo, list);

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blood_Request").orderByKey();

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                blood_request_model = ds.getValue(Blood_Request_Model.class);
                key = ds.getKey();
                list.add("I am "+blood_request_model.getName()+
                        ". I need "+blood_request_model.getHow()+" "+ blood_request_model.getBlood()+ " blood at "+blood_request_model.getLocation()+" For my "
                        +blood_request_model.getRelation());

            }
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

    listview.setClickable(true);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(BloodReqActivity.this, BloodReqUpdate.class);
            i.putExtra("modelkey", key);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }

    });



    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });

}

} ]
```

Anyone please help to solve this problem. I want every time I click the different item resoponse.

Comment: In your `for` loop, your `key` keeps on updating until the last item in the iteration, it would be better to create a custom data holder class with all the relevant objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your position lets you identify which item was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this. `i.putExtra("modelkey", list.get(positin).key);` because you didn't define the position of value from array-list which are related with the position listview.

```
    listview.setClickable(true);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(BloodReqActivity.this, BloodReqUpdate.class);
                i.putExtra("modelkey", list.get(position).key);
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
    
            }
    
        });
```

still having problem, comment here.